# SQL to combine two records into one

Tags: sql, oracle11g

The table I am working with uses two rows to record each 'transaction': one row to identify the party acting, the second row to identify the party acted upon.  The data contents differ only in the value of one field, a logical flag of 'Y' or 'N'.  For example, I might have this:

```
E-num  E-date       Client   Actor
1234   2013-05-02   ACME     Y
1234   2013-05-02   ALLIED   N
```

What I would like to report is this:

```
E-num  E-date       For      Against
1234   2013-05-02   ACME     ALLIED
```

Thanks, folks.
Terry

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? The best answer depends on whether it's MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle, etc.

Comment: @Barmar You are right, ofc. The Title says SQL, the tag says SQL - but due to "1" post and the question itself, I would predict *MySQL* to be the RDBMS :-)

Comment: Yeah, I could have been more specific.  It was/is Oracle 11g.

Comment: Didn't you notice the big reminder box when you were writing the question? When you use the sql tag, it suggest that you add a more specific tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just join the table on the `E-num` and pick the rows as required.

If you are using MySQL, the Query would be

```
   SELECT
     t1.E-num,
     t1.E-date,
     t1.Client AS 'For',
     t2.Client AS Against
   FROM
     `transaction` t1
   INNER JOIN
     `transaction` t2
   ON 
     t1.E-num = t2.E-num
   WHERE
     t1.Actor = 'Y' AND
     t2.Actor = 'N'
```

Untest, but it should give you an idea.

Comment: Note that this is not Oracle 11g compliant. `-` is not working in column names unless you enclose it in `""` and enclosing `transaction` with ````  is wrong as well. Finally there's a `;` missing, `For` needs to be enclosed in `"` and the date has not been considered.

Comment: My apologies.  The example columns were fictitious, made up to simplify the example and save me some typing.  I adapted your solution without any problem, though.

Comment: @Trinimon I left out the date, cause i assumed `E-num` to be a surrogate id for the transaction (which seems to be a sender/receiver tuple) . Even if backticks are not required for table names - it never hurts to add them (not sure on oracle, that information has been provided later). Even if it is not a "copy&paste" solution, Terrence managed to adapt it, which is the important thing ;)

Comment: @dognose: no problem and I didn't down vote as you noticed. I've been stoned for much less in this forum ;) The backticks you used are not allowed in ORACLE - you have to use `""` instead; same for `''`. I just wanted to point out that this is not ORACLE compliant, because less experienced users might be confused.

Answer (score 0):

An ORACLE version: use a self-join of your table:

```
SELECT t1."E-num", t1."E-date", t1."Client" as "For", t2."Client" as "Against"
  FROM transaction t1, transaction t2
 WHERE t1."E-num"  = t2."E-num"
   AND t1."E-date" = t2."E-date"
   AND t1."Actor" = 'Y'
   AND t2."Actor" = 'N';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use pivot for this...

```
with t as (
    select [E-num] = 1234, [E-date] = '5/2/2013', [Client] = 'ACME', Actor = 'Y'
    union select 1234, '5/2/2013', 'ALLIED', 'N'
)

select
    p.[E-num],
    p.[E-date],
    [For] = p.[Y],
    [Against] = p.[N]
from
    t
    pivot (
        max(Client)
        for Actor in ([Y],[N])
    ) p
```

Comment: Way over my head, but thanks for the answer, dotjoe.